# Label displays completely at first instead of fading in like I want it too

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to make a `CCLabelTTF` fade in then fade out.

This is the code I am using to do this:

```
CCLabelTTF *intro = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Welcome" fontName:@"Times New Roman" fontSize:30];
[intro setPosition:ccp(240, 110)];
[intro runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:2.0f], [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:2.0f], nil]];
[self addChild:intro];
```

It sort of works, but when I run the program the `CCLabelTTF intro` quickly shows itself completely (with an opacity of 1.0f, kind of like a quick blink) then it disappears and fades in and out like it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you set it's opacity to zero?

```
[intro setOpacity:0];
```